# ObjC - Hiding the separator lines of a UITableView on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I try to do this with following line:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

and it works! on the simulator.. strangely when I run the app on the iPhone (3Gs) they show up again.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

(Also labels and images of my custom cells are displayed on wrong positions, maybe its the same problem)

There is absolutely no difference between the simulator and the device code (it's the same code that gets compiled).

Comment: Oh, and I am initializing tableView with 
tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:rect style:UITableViewStylePlain];
so it is not the group style bug

Comment: Thanks 4 sharing dkk, this is was exactly what i was searching for!

Comment: Why not set the separator color to clear color?

Comment: @Dio: I believe you do that, then the background of the tableview will show through, leading to an undesired "feature."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was an Apple bug. I updated to iOS 4.0.1 (with XCode+SDK update as well of course) and now everything works just fine.